# Cannot get main to work with binary tree implementation?

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I've checked up and down and the implementation of my binary tree seems correct and works for the implementation that is commented out with /* */ but for my int main while loop the insert does not insert and store the value at root (the first value) and checked that it does store the value in the functions but the second call says its null again. Can you explain whats wrong with my main file in connection with the binary tree? I would greatly appreciate it!

-> http://ideone.com/w9Aa1w  (my function implentation with the commented code working)

```
using namespace std;
int choice = 6;
string value;
int main(void)
 {
  //not working implentation

   while(choice != 5){

  //binary tree test
    cout << "Enter 1 to insert " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to search " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to display tree " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 4 to delete tree " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 5 to exit.. " << endl;
       Tree<std::string> B;
    cout << "Your choice -> : " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

 if(choice == 1)
 {
        cout << "Enter value to insert: ";
         cin >> value;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Inserting new node! " << endl;
        B.insertTree(value);
 }

 if(choice == 2)
 {   
        cout << "Enter value to search: ";
         cin >> value;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Search for value..." << endl;
        B.searchTree();

  if(choice == 3)
  {    
       cout << "Displaying tree data" << endl;
       B.displayTree();
  }
  if(choice == 4)
  {
       cout << "Deleting tree data" << endl;
       B.deleteTree();     
  }                    
   if(choice == 5)
   cout << "exiting..." << endl;          
  }

    /* //Working part of program seperate function**********

Tree<std::string> tree;
    tree.insertTree(std::string("Hello"));
    tree.insertTree(std::string("World"));

    Tree<std::string>::node* node = tree.searchTree("World");

    cout << node << endl;

     return 0; */
```

Comment: This is not C.  Please remove the C tag.

Comment: All sorts of tag abuse all over the place. Cleaned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tree `B` is going out of scope with each iteration of your loop.

```
while(choice != 5){
   //...
   Tree<std::string> B;
   //...
}
```

You need to move it so that it stays in scope for the duration of the run:

```
Tree<std::string> B;

while(choice != 5){
   //...
   //...
}
```

Comment: thank you Chad was looking at my header file the whole time assuming my function definitions were the cause of this problem when the problem was that simple and I just had a friend tell me a moment ago that he bets the problem is the simplest thing in the world... haha